# regarding connecting GUI to app code for data aquisiton

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Language used: python 2.7
GUI package: Tkinter

Goal: Create a  GUI program that will interface with several different DAQ devices.
Right now I am trying to acheive this for only one device.

Current Status: I have application code for one of the devices. I have a a basic GUI and need to connect the application code to the GUI

Question: I want to know exactly how do I connect the GUI to the application code. I can retrieve data from the device and now I need to be able to plot that data. 
Can any one suggest some things to me. I am stuck

Comment: Can you explain more about the application code you have? Is it in Python? Did you write it or did it come from somewhere else?

Comment: THe application code is in python. The device has a API thats written in c. There was an existing python library that basically converted the C functions into python functions. The application code allows one to retrieve data from each of the channels in the DAQ device.

Comment: write the data you get in a file,parse the file according to your needs & then maybe you can use that data to plot that data...atleast thats how i did it!